# aspnet_compiler Unknown server tag 'sc:sublayout'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, aspnet-compiler

I have no error or warnings when i build my visual studio 2012 solution file.

However, when i tried using aspnet_compiler, I got lots of errors such as" Error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag 'sc:placeholder' and also Error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag 'sc:sublayout'"

I did some googling and found out that I require some tagPrefix in my web.config file.

Link: http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.sg/2012/03/include-sc-namespace.html

However, I already have the following tagPrefix in my web.config file

```
 <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Analytics" />
</controls>
```

Can anyone provide me any insight on how can I resolve this weird issue?

Comment: check answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311088/new-habitat-project-unrecognised-sitecore-tags

Comment: check answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311088/new-habitat-project-unrecognised-sitecore-tags