# New Habitat project - unrecognised Sitecore Tags

Tags: sitecore-habitat

I've inherited a skeleton Sitecore project based on Habitat (Sitecore 8.2 Update 6) but when I access the /sitecore url I'm getting the error:

```
Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'sc:PlatformFontStylesLink'.
```

In my folder serving the web site, I've used the web.config as supplied by a new Sitecore Instance Manager instance (this will be transformed by Habitat)

sc:PlatformFontStylesLink is a control Sitecore itself uses so for some reason it can't resolve the server tag. I'm guessing this is due to a configuration issue but Im not sure what exactly. The web.config includes this line:

```
<add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

Comment: Changed tag 'habitat' to 'sitecore-habitat'. Part of effort to split up ambiguous tag 'habitat'

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of your sitecore.kernel.dll.  Likely it is incorrect.

I've seen that happen if a project in your visual studio solution is referencing the wrong version of sitecore - and "copy local" is set to true.

So to fix this:

1. Restore the correct version of sitecore.kernel.dll t your site's bin folder (probably a good idea to check all your sitecore*.*.dlls )
2. Find the offending project - update the reference - and set "copy local" to false.

Also - seeing that you inherited a Sitecore site, and are likely to have more questions down the road - thee is a more specialized [Sitecore Stack Exchange site.](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/) you might want to check out.